# APN works in development not in distribution

Tags: ios

We have an iPhone app that uses APN, the testing was perfect on sandbox, now the problem we are seeing is that APN is not reaching the phone on production, is this a known issue on the iPhone? Our app was just approved two days ago.

We checked everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707150/iphone-push-notification-works-in-sandbox-but-not-in-production-mode),
I understand this question is very hard to answer and I guess what I'm looking for is any hints.

This is what I made sure of:

- I am using different APN token for production than development
- The provisioning profile has Push Notifications enabled
- Apple APN service responds successfully without and don't report any issue.
- Certificates seems to be fine. And when I unzip the ipa I see `aps-environment` refers to `production` in the distribution ipa.
- Downloaded the Store ipa and unpacked it, yet to find that it also has the aps-environment set to production.

  ---

  **UPDATE:**

I removed all the certificates and provisioning profiles and created a new Production/Distribution certificate with Push Notification support.

Now, when I installed the store version, the APN didn't work still. However, I used the latest Ad-Hoc built I have locally and the APN is working fine. I decided to replace the Ad-Hoc with the Store version, and behold, the APN started to work. I am not sure what's the issue, I'll have to check on other phones to see if it really works. Have anyone had similar scenario?

Comment: have you downloaded the binary from app store and are trying then ?

Comment: Yes, I did that and and I found out the aps-enviroment was production as well.

Comment: Notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered, but this seems extreme. Are you using your own server to send or a third-party?

Comment: I am using my own server with my own C language implementation of the enhanced APN. It delivers fine, and do not disconnect.

Comment: no no my question is have you downloaded your application from app store, installed it  and are trying then

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had the same troubles.

Just found this link: [iPhone iOS push notifications apns on production not sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095134/iphone-ios-push-notifications-apns-on-production-not-sending)

For production you need a different URL to push your notifications:

```
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 Development

ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 Production
```

This fixed it for me.